# I am having abc.mdf database in D drive and i want to use in my website using web.config?

Tags: asp.net

I am having abc.mdf database in D drive and i want to use in my website and i have tried as in web.config

**and i got following error**

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file D:\abc.mdf
>   failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot
>   be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

I am sure database doesn't exists anywhere else.Please help

Comment: can you show your connection string?

Comment: <connectionStrings>  
    <add name="connectionstring" connectionString="Data Source=.; AttachDbFilename=D:\vik.mdf;Integrated Security=True;
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: If I am using User Instance=true with above it raises error that     " The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server. The connection will be closed."

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure "vik.mdf" file is not already placed in MSSQL Data folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA) or database is not already attached in Microsoft SQL server Management Studio.

Comment: If I want To use it from D drive is it not possible??? I am sure that my database exists only in D drive no where else....Help please..

Answer (score 0):

When you report that "If I am using User Instance=true with above it raises error...  The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server" it sounds like you aren't using SQLEXPRESS. Only SQLEXPRESS supports user instances.